# Silverlight 2 Drag and Drop tutorials

Tags: silverlight

I'm wondering if people can suggest the best tutorial that will walk me through the best way to do Drag and Drop with control collision detection etc, using MS Silverlight V2.

I've done the [Jesse Liberty tutorials](http://silverlight.net/learn/tutorials.aspx) at Silverlight.net, and they were a good introduction, but I'm looking for something a bit deeper.

Suggestions?

UPDATE: Here is the summary of the list of answers for convenience:

1. http://www.adefwebserver.com/DotNetNukeHELP/Misc/Silverlight/DragAndDropTest/
2. [Lee’s corner](http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2008/04/11/drag-and-drop-in-silverlight/)
3. [Corey Schuman](http://simplesilverlight.wordpress.com/2008/08/13/drag-and-drop-silverlight-example/)
4. [MARTIN GRAYSON: ADVENTURES OF A 'DEVIGNER'](http://blogs.msdn.com/mgrayson/archive/2008/08/18/silverlight-2-samples-dragging-docking-expanding-panels-part-2.aspx)
5. http://www.codeplex.com/silverlightdragdrop
6. [Nick Polyak’s Software Blog](http://nickssoftwareblog.com/2008/10/07/silverlight-20-in-examples-part-drag-and-drop-inside-out/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a page that explained the solution for my use.

[Silverlight 2 Drag, Drop, and Import Content Example](http://www.adefwebserver.com/DotNetNukeHELP/Misc/Silverlight/DragAndDropTest/)

Answer (score 3):

Here are three more pages that have examples and code:

http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2008/04/11/drag-and-drop-in-silverlight/

http://simplesilverlight.wordpress.com/2008/08/13/drag-and-drop-silverlight-example/

http://blogs.msdn.com/mgrayson/archive/2008/08/18/silverlight-2-samples-dragging-docking-expanding-panels-part-2.aspx

Answer (score 1):

A codeplex project for drag and drop http://www.codeplex.com/silverlightdragdrop

Answer (score 1):

The following tutorial is helpful, and the author has posted code, including a drag and drop control you can download: 
http://nickssoftwareblog.com/2008/10/07/silverlight-20-in-examples-part-drag-and-drop-inside-out/

I am currently using this control in a new Silverlight application.